# Force Phonegap(Android) splash screen orientation

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I added a splash screen to my phonegap application by adding the `super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);` line before the `super.loadURL...` line in the `DefaultActivity`.

Is there a way to lock only the splash screen's orientation to portrait without locking the whole application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of PhoneGap (DroidGap) or Apache Cordova you can force screen orientation to landscape by changing your screenOrientation in the Android.xml file.  The resulting DroidGap "instantiation activity" should look something like this:

```
        <activity 
        android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"           
        > 
        <intent-filter> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>
```

Comment: Doesn't this lock the entire application's orientation to landscape?  The original question is about locking the splash screen orientation to portrait without locking the orientation of the entire app.

Answer (score 5):

After many searches I've found that the right way to address splash screen orientation is to manage **two images** using this code into your `MainActivity`

```
 if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2) {
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splashlandscape);
        Log.d("Orientation", "Landscape");
    }
    else {
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splashportrait);
        Log.d("Orientation", "Portrait");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The following solution works for Cordova 3+ on Android and iOS. It locks orientation for the splashscreen only, then unlocks it once the app is running.

Fix the orientation in config.xml:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Then use this [screen orientation plugin](https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation) to unlock it once the app has initialised:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    screen.unlockOrientation();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the following inside the onCreate method of the splashscreen activity:

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that with Phonegap, the splashscreen isn't a separate Activity. If I force the orientation to that Activity, I force the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```